# How to add JSP variable in jQuery?

Tags: json, jsp

I am getting some JSON data from a file `db.jsp`. The jsp file gets user details from my database and prints as a JSON format I am using get method to achieve this.

My url should be like : `db.jsp?userid=DIBYA` the value 'DIBYA' here is input form the user. I am trying to concatenate as:

```
function submit() {
    $.getJSON('db.jsp?userid='+<%String userName = request.getParameter("userid"); out.print(userName);%>, function(data) {
```

But, my console shows an error message as `ReferenceError: DIBYA is not defined`. Please tell me what changes do I need in my code?

Thanks

Dibya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line

```
$.getJSON('db.jsp?userid='+<%String userName = "DIBYA"; out.print(userName);%>, function(data) {
```

will be translated by the JSP container to the following JavaScript code:

```
$.getJSON('db.jsp?userid='+DIBYA, function(data) {
```

So the JavaScript engine in the browser will look for a JavaScript variable named DIBYA.

If you just want the value to be the string DIBYA, I don't even understand why you use a scriptlet. Just use

```
$.getJSON('db.jsp?userid=DIBYA', function(data) {
```

Comment: In my case I take the username form the users as input in a form. I omitted that for simplicity. Edited the question.

Comment: Your explanation gave me hint what should be the solution. In the page where I was using the form I can use the solution you provided but, I will set a session using userId, so for that propose I have use the scriptlet.

Comment: Don't use scriptlets. Use the JSP EL and the JSTL: `$.getJSON('db.jsp?userid=${theSessionAttribute}', function(data)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will use this method, seems I don't have to use JSP at all in jQuery.

Comment: `${theSessionAttribute}` is another, cleaner way, to access a session attribute. It's executed at server side. JavaScript is executed at client side. The session can't be accessed at client side.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put quotes around “DIBYA”. Your code expands to:

```
function submit() {
    $.getJSON('db.jsp?userid='+DIBYA, function(data) {
```

but you want:

```
function submit() {
    $.getJSON('db.jsp?userid='+'DIBYA', function(data) {
```

or better:

```
function submit() {
    $.getJSON('db.jsp?userid=DIBYA', function(data) {
```

So you need to write like that:

```
function submit() {
    $.getJSON('db.jsp?userid=<% out.print(userName);%>', function(data) {
```

Comment: Well I have given a demo where I know the user name but I have mentioned that I will use the username variable as input from the users.

Comment: Of course. I put the code after it was expanded by the JSP engine.